# How do I get a standalone (no install necessary) JDK 8 for Java coding in IDE on Mac?

Tags: mac, administrator, jdk

I am using a public computer and I want to do some Java coding on it. I was able to download IntelliJ and I was able to copy it to my desktop and run it, but I was not able to install the JDK due to lack of administrator privileges.

How do I get a standalone (no install necessary) JDK 8 to use with IntelliJ on Mac? Screenshots below for reference.

IntelliJ running from the desktop:

[image: IntelliJ running from the desktop.]

Can’t install JDK without administrator privileges:

[image: Can’t install JDK without administrator privileges.]

Answer (score 0):

Use an online Java editor and compiler. Ones that allow you to register (non-anonymous use) can save your work. With a public computer the session is usually reset per user to clean up after the previous person.

- [JDoodle.com](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler)
- [Tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php)
- [Browxy.com](http://www.browxy.com/)

There is no [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) for Java here, nor is one likely; probably part of the reason installation is blocked on public computers. With many of the online editor/compilers you can link to your creation and they **will** run it on their server; that allows you to include a link to a working (partly broken) example here on SE/SO.

An alternative is to get [shell account](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_account) somewhere and you can log into it from a public computer.